# About get event log use EvtOpenSession (Why filling the domain parameter with any text can be success?)

Tags: c++, windows, remote-server, event-log

I need to connect to the remote server to read the event log. I use [EvtOpenSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtopensession) function to connect and connect successfully.

My question is: why setting the parameter of Domain to any string will connect successfully?(The actual domain is "testad.com" ex:Set Credentials.Domain = L"123"; or Credentials.Domain = NULL;)

```
void main()
{
    const wchar_t *channelPath = L"Security";
    const wchar_t *query = L"Event/System[((EventID=4728) or (EventID = 4729))]";
    //Remote handle
    EVT_HANDLE hRemoteHandle;
    EVT_RPC_LOGIN Credentials;
    RtlZeroMemory(&Credentials, sizeof(EVT_RPC_LOGIN));

    wstring comp_name = L"TEST-AD";  //server name
    wstring user_name = L"<username>";
    wstring password = L"<password>";

    Credentials.Server = &comp_name[0];
    Credentials.Domain = L"testad.com"; //NULL; //L"123";  //Will be connected successfully, No matter what string is

    Credentials.User = &user_name[0];
    Credentials.Password = &password[0];
    Credentials.Flags = EvtRpcLoginAuthNTLM;
    hRemoteHandle = EvtOpenSession(EvtRpcLogin, &Credentials, 0, 0);
    hResults = EvtQuery(hRemoteHandle , channelPath, query, EvtQueryChannelPath| 
                        EvtQueryForwardDirection);
}
```